# Velocity: Spaces before or after #if, #else and #end?

Tags: java, velocity

I inherited several projects that use some Velocity code.
http://velocity.apache.org/

My question may be simple and perhaps a bit naive to those who are more experienced with Velocity, but I have to fix bugs that deal with `extra spaces` or `missing spaces` in the code.

```
#if (${INCOMPLETE_ACCOUNT})Click "Use Now" to confirm your new Acme ID account $!{MM_ID}. You will be asked to create a password if you haven’t already done so. #elseClick below to download or sign into your new products.#end
```

Is this valid? I asked co-workers whether we need spaces before or after the `else` and `end`, but they claimed they didn't know. Someone said, "Always put a space before `#end`." However, they don't actually follow that rule.

I found some documentation that explained that the `else` within text (as in my example above) should be used like so:

```
#if( $foo == $bar)it's true!#{else}it's not!#end
```

(See: http://people.apache.org/~henning/velocity/html/ch05s03.html)

Question: Where do I need spaces? And is `#{else}` currently safe to use? Is there one way that's recommended? How are you using `#if`, `#else` and #end in your code?

Comment: add to my answer also option regarding the text after else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need [spaces](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#vtl-formatting-issues) in velocity:

> Velocity's behaviour is to gobble up excess whitespace.

```
#set($foo=["$10 and ","a pie"])#foreach($a in $foo)$a#end
```

Sometimes you can't add spaces because your file you are rendering is intolerant for spaces.

About writing text right after else with `#{else}`, you can change to use velocity comments after, as suggested in [mailing list](http://grokbase.com/t/velocity/user/053c1km0pe/extra-space-appearing-in-the-if-else-block):

```
#if( $foo == $bar)it's true!#else#**#it's not!#end
```